# Test a Nullable Guid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tdd

I'm using ASP.NET MVC + C# and I have two controller action as follows:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{

}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(SomeModel model)
{

}
```

Now, in the browser I can navigate to the [GET] /controller/edit with no id and get an null argument exception (as expected), but what I'd like to know is how do I replicate this scenario in a unit test?

I have a GET and a POST version of the edit method so I can't feed `controller.Edit(null)` to test it as the code won't compile.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the other method also take a type that can be `null` as an argument? I am having a difficult time seeing how the controller compiles with two edit methods that both take a `Nullable<Guid>`.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the `ActionName` attribute to keep the URL the same, but have different method names.

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult GetEditForm(Guid? id)
{
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Edit")]
public ActionResult SaveEditForm(SomeModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you could of course call the right method from your unit test, and the routing bits of ASP.NET take care of getting the right method called.

Comment: Yeah - deleted mine once I saw you deleted yours. Do you think we will also do the same with these? :)

Comment: Not this time :D I left it there once I saw you'd deleted yours! Thanks the the answer!